# string to decimal showing always two decimals

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I have this string "121,121.00" and I need to convert to a decimal to give to the front-end this '121121.00'. I have tried a lot but I can't do it yet. Here some code I tried and the results they gave me:

```
string var = "121,121.00"

decimal d = decimal.Parse(var, NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
// it gives me '12112100'  

decimal d = decimal.Parse(var, NumberStyles.Currency);
// it gives me '12112100' 

decimal d = decimal.Parse((var.Replace(",","")), NumberStyles.Currency);
// and it gives me '12112100' too
```

Comment: It's been a little while since I've worked with c#, but I expect you'll need to set the locale.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the clumsy edit. I didn't mean to take out the semi-colons.

Comment: `"121,121.00".Replace(",", "")`? Looks like you are confusing with decimal and it's string representation.

Comment: Your "result" is a decimal, it is just a number, it does not have a format, the formatting is on reading the string.

Comment: I know that the result is a decimal, but the function always concatenates the decimals with the number, I need the real number with two decimals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A decimal has just a value, you are confusing it with a string which can diplay a number in a desired format. You can use `d.ToString("0.00)"` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
string var = "121,121.00";
decimal number = decimal.Parse(var, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = number.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I need to get a decimal value Tim, but what the 'decimal.Parse' do is always concatenates the decimal with the number. I need to get the number it doesn't matter if it shows the zeros or not, but if the decimals != zero I need to show them and always the number as decimal

Comment: @JuanFranciscoCaballero: have you tried my code? It returns `121121.00` as desired.

Comment: and the name 'var' was an error it is not the real name of the string. I'm sorry hahaha

Comment: @JuanFranciscoCaballero: `var` is perfectly valid for the compiler, but you haven't answered my question. Does it work? If not, what is wrong?

Comment: Yeap bro! it works! Thanks a lot after a whole day I finally do it! hahaha

Answer (score 3):

Numbers don't have trailing zero decimals.

If you want to display them in a certain way (as opposed to just working with them) then you need to convert them to a string, ie `number.ToString("0.00")` -- however it's somewhat funny because you start with a string in the first place.

Comment: Also `var` is a keyword in C#. Perhaps a different name would be better. One that's more descriptive for instance.

Comment: What I mean is that always the function concatenates the decimals with the number.. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

Simple single step process - Parse the decimal directly as:

```
var decimalValue = decimal.Parse(decimalString);
```

so, `decimal.Parse("121,121.00")` will return a `decimal value - 121121.00`. Don't need to worry about strings and cultureinfo at all.